# Data is changing from Upper case to lower case while doing Find and Replace

Tags: c#

I'm working on FIND and REPLACE functionality in datagridview.

Below is the result after working on it.

```
S.No
-----
CODE0001
CODE0002
CODE0003
CODE0004
```

Where `S.No` is the column name.

When I FIND 0001 and ask to replace that with 1000, the result is,

```
S.No
-----
code1000
CODE0002
CODE0003
CODE0004
```

Find and Replace functionality is working but the text from UPPERCASE is changing to LOWERCASE.

Below is the code for Find and Repalce:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Replace(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower(), f.txtreplace.Text);
        bulidDataRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be typing ctrl + u by mistake. Please confirm. 

ctrl + u are the keys used to make the text to the lower case.

Comment: Delete `.ToLower()` wherever it occurs

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ToUpper();` at the end, after replace:

```
Value.ToString().ToLower().Replace(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower(), f.txtreplace.Text).ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your resulting string to be completely uppercase then add .ToUpper() to the result.

If you want to maintain case in your string then Replace is not capable. You will need to do something like this:

```
string x = Value.ToString();
string o = f.txtfind.Text.ToLower();
string n = f.txtreplace.Text;
while (x.ToLower().Contains(o))
{
    x = x.SubString(0, x.ToLower().IndexOf(o)) + n + x.SubString(x.ToLower().IndexOf(o) + o.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `ToLower` to do a case-insensitive replace. You could use `Regex.Replace` instead, which allows you to specify `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. Perhaps like this:

```
var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text];
var oldValue = cell.Value.ToString();
cell.Value = Regex.Replace(cell.Value.ToString(), f.cmbColumnCombo.Text, f.txtreplace.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if ((string)cell.Value != oldValue)
     bulidDataRow(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an case insensitive search and replace, I think the easiest way is to use regular expressions.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString()
                    .ToLower()
                    .Contains(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        string input = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString();
        string pattern = f.txtfind.Text.ToLower();
        string replacement = f.txtreplace.Text;
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = output
                bulidDataRow(i);
    }
}
```

If you want all thing in upper case, you can use:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToUpper().Replace(f.txtfind.Text.ToUpper(), f.txtreplace.Text);
```